# Python and BS4 - stop reading after certain amount of times

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First time Python 3 user and starting to get the hang of it. As an exercise I'm trying to read the table (with BeautifulSoup4) from http://rateyourmusic.com/customchart and convert the Rank, Artist, Album, and Year into a dictionary. I want to then put the dictionary into a MySQL database. I was able to get all the info from the table and put them into variables which I then put into a dictionary, but I have a slight problem. The last entry in the table is an advertisement so it doesn't follow the other table rows above it. I want to only read the first 100 rows of the table. I get an error when trying to read the advertisement row.

Here is my code. Please any help would be great. Also if you see any errors in my code or how I could've done things better please let me know.

So it is printing the dictionaries and everything looks good, but it gives me an error after printing all of them out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "http://rateyourmusic.com/customchart"
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req))

table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "mbgen"})
totalList = []

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    rank = int(cells[0].find(class_="ooookiig").text)
    artist = cells[2].find(class_="artist").text
    album = cells[2].find(class_="album").text
    year = cells[2].find(class_="mediumg").text
    year = int(year[1:5])

    chartData = {"Rank":rank, "Artist":artist, "Album":album, "Year":year}
    totalList.append(chartData)
    print(chartData)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\RateYourMusicCrawler\AlbumInfoCrawler.py", line 21, in <module>
    rank = int(cells[0].find(class_="ooookiig").text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate with a counter and stop as soon as the counter reaches 100, but I don't like that very much, the code won't be useful anymore of they decide to increment the number of elements to 200 for example. I would use a simple `try` block like the following:

```
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    try:
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        rank = int(cells[0].find(class_="ooookiig").text)
        artist = cells[2].find(class_="artist").text
        album = cells[2].find(class_="album").text
        year = cells[2].find(class_="mediumg").text
        year = int(year[1:5])

        chartData = {"Rank":rank, "Artist":artist, "Album":album, "Year":year}
        totalList.append(chartData)
        print(chartData)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much PepperoniPizza!!! Solved my problem instantly. I'm not used to catching errors yet. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the parser couldn't find the item.

From BS4 [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

> If find_all() can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If find() can’t find anything, it returns None

You can use a try block, but personally, i prefer to check it manually:

```
for rownumber, row in enumerate(table.findAll('tr')):
    if rownumber < 100:
        #do something
```